# Embedding links in WordPress 3.6

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a theme for WordPress 3.6 and as far as I know embedded links, like if just place a link into the post for YouTube it should auto embed its self. that's not the case here - would any one know what would cause links from services like YouTube to not embed?

`[embed][/embed]` doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure the YouTube link is not hyperlinked. If the URL is shown in
  your theme’s link color (as the second line in the screenshot below),
  then it is hyperlinked. Simply select the whole URL and click the
  “Unlink” icon on your Visual Editor toolbar.
- Once the URL is unlinked, you will see the link text in black. Make
  sure to place the YouTube URL or shortcode on its own line. This
  means there should be no character or whitespace before or after the 
  URL/shortcode.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/

However, beyond those issues you might want to look into. the API that WP uses to embed links from YouTube, Twitter, Flicker...

http://oembed.com/

oEmbed is a format for allowing an embedded representation of a URL on third party sites. The simple API allows a website to display embedded content (such as photos or videos) when a user posts a link to that resource, without having to parse the resource directly.

Comment: The link is just text in my theme, like it doesn't show up as a link, its not clickable, its just text as a link to a youtube video when it should show the youtube video its self.

Answer (score 0):

Unlink the link if it's linked and use the shortcode : 
[youtube=http://www.youtube.com/XXXX] and that will work.